# Call long running activity inside Azure Durable Orchestrator

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

My requirement is, i have a console application which does 'n' number of activities which may last for 30 minutes. Can I port this long running application code to Azure Durable function without refactoring so that durable function will withstand 30 mins execution period? With code refactoring I know we can have different activities to different Azure activity function & get it done via durable function though entire process takes around 30 minutes. But I want to do it without code refactoring, any options in durable function to support such use case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do need to move the actual work to activity functions.
The orchestrator itself is only expected to start activities, sub-orchestrators etc.

The only issue you might run into here is that an activity function is basically a normal queue-triggered function, which have a maximum execution time. On consumption plan, that's 5 minutes by default (can be increased to 10 minutes). But, if you run the functions on an App Service plan, it can be increased to anything you want (since the instances are dedicated at that point). More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale